# Custom Docker jenkins image mounted on Azure Web App on Linux loses saved configuration data

Tags: linux, azure, docker, jenkins

A Jenkins docker image uploaded to an azure docker registry and ran on an Azure Linux web app, the security and first user is configured and works.

When we stop the web app and start it again the configuration is lost.

Is this working as intended? Do we have to connect it to a blob for persistence and configuration?

Is there an easier way to keep the configuration data/save data?

As far as I know there's no way to run docker commands on a docker image on an azure Linux web app.

DockerFile:

```
FROM jenkins:1.609.1

USER root

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m"
ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--handlerCountStartup=100 --handlerCountMax=300"

COPY logging.properties /docker-java-home/jre/lib/logging.properties  

USER jenkins

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: This is way too light on the details. What image was uploaded? What is the `Dockerfile` for the image? How was it run on "Azure Linux web app"? How was it stopped?

Comment: what do you mean how was it run? there's only 1 way to do that. dockerfile contents are irrelevant, the problem is not in how the image was built. again, there's only 1 way to stop it. your comment is useless at best @AndyShinn

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what they are running, there are all kinds of settings for running Docker images as an Azure Web App: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-custom-docker-image. There is the image, startup command, environment variables, ports. The `Dockerfile` defines stuff like default command to run and volumes. The container cold have been stopped from the command line of the host in some way or the Azure console (both having an affect on whether the container is removed or not). All of this is relevant for troubleshooting.

Comment: I stopped and started the app with the ARM portal under app->overview -> stop button/start button. Thanks for help!

Comment: all of that is irrelevant to the problem, also you cant talk to docker to stop\start the container on the webapp. @AndyShinn

Comment: I guess you have a magic ability to know the problem and solution without any debugging information. What a gift! I'll let you answer the question since I guess I am going down the wrong path.

Comment: `/var/jenkins_home` should be using persistent storage. If your jenkins container gets recreated you loose all the data. I'm sure Azure have docs on how to do this. I'm guessing you just need a `VOLUME /var/jenkins_home` in your dockerfile, but I might be wrong.